# Abstract Classes, Function Inheritance and Override in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods

Class A is abstract class. I would like to call the same method from different subclasses. There are no errors from compiler, but program crashes.

```
class A
{
    protected:

        MA* array1[10]; //static array of pointers to some other class
        int st;

    public:
    ...
        virtual string ToString() const
        {
            stringstream ss;

            for(int i=0;i<st;i++)
            {
                ss<<array1[i]->getname()<<",";
            }

            return ss.str();
        }
};
```

ToString method works in both classes A and B but doesn't work in class C

```
class B: public A
{
    private:
    ...

    public:

        string ToString() const
        {
            return A::ToString();
        }
};

class C: public A
{
    private:
    ...

    public:

        string ToString() const
        {
            return A::ToString();    
        }
};
```

This is main:

```
A* P[5];
P[0]=new B();
P[1]=new C();
P[0]->ToString();
P[1]->ToString();
```

Comment: `st` is never initialized in this code... Where are you initializing it? `ToString` can't possibly work unless it has a value < 10. (And if it's non-zero, where are you initializing `array1`?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it works in neither A nor B.

The only reason it seems to would be Undefined Behaviour.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

  1. The problem I anticipate is a Rule-Of-Three violation (make A non-copyable?).

     - [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)
  2. alternatively, do you initialize `array1` and `st` properly? Failing to do so will lead to indeterminate values in the array, and thus, Undefined Behaviour again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue:

First, your derived classes (B and C) are inheriting Class A's public member functions (I know this is obvious looking at the code - but, we have to start somewhere); *however*, the derived classes are overriding your Parent class's (Class A) member functions by utilizing the same function identifier. The issue here is that the Parent does not expect the inheriting - derived - classes to override the parent classes, which they are doing. The Parent only expects the derived classes to inherit; therefore, when you call the function of Class B and Class C, something weird is happening.

Two issues arise as a result: first (1), that which we discuss above (see code, below); second (2), the derived classes do not have access to the Parent class's member function definition unless called via an object of the parent class (*which would not normally be the case, here, were your functions properly declared*).

So, what can you do? Use the **override** keyword in your Parent declaration and in your child declaration.

For instance:

```
Class A
{
    private:
    ....
    public:
    virtual returntype functionIndentifier(parameters) override;
};
```

Now, that has to do with inheritance; however, in C++, were your class *actually* abstract, you would need to use a **pure virtual** function (by setting the function equal to 0), not defining the function in the abstract class, leaving out the **override** keyword, and ensuring each child class implements - and defines - the function.

```
Class A
{
    private:
    ....
    public:
    virtual returntype functionIndentifier(parameters) = 0;
};
```

**pure virtual** functions force a child class to both inherit *and* implement - define - a member function to the child class's needs. Here, if the pure virtual class were not defined in your child's class definition, then - I believe - you would in fact encounter a compile-time error.